# CSS background-image not showing

Tags: css, background-image

I'm new to CSS and when I try to insert a `background-image` it won't show up.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#logo {
   background-image: url(../images/logo.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 376px;
   height: 81px;
   margin-top: 28px;
   margin-left: 128px;
}
```

Comment: add semi-colons after height and width and make sure that this image path is correct

Comment: Open your page with Chrome inspector and click on the image url to check it works.

Comment: Make sure your image path is correct and as others have said please add semi-colons after your width & height attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need quotes around the path in the URL, and semi-colons after the height & width

```css
#logo {
    background-image: url("../images/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 376px;
    height: 81px;
    margin-top: 28px;
    margin-left: 128px;
}
```

Comment: Quotes around the url are optional.

Comment: OK - I never knew that they were optional - useful

Comment: I've done what you guys did, but still doesn't work. I'm 100% sure the path is correct because when I put the same path as and img src in html it does find it. code looks like this now.
  
#logo {
 background-image: url(../images/logo.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 376px;
 height: 81px;
 margin-top: 28px;
 margin-left: 128px;
 }

Comment: The image path is relative to the css file - so the fact it works in html is irrelevant

Comment: But my css file is in the same folder as my html file

Comment: OK - Open the page in Chrome, press F12 to open Developer Tools and select the network tab - then hit F5 to refresh the page - do you see the image load, or is there an error - that will determine whether it is a path issue or something else.

Comment: copy the image from the images folder and paste it in the folder containing css files.Then give `background-image:url("logo.png");` .Report the output

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I missed 1 folder, thanks a lot BonyT for pointing it out with the F12

Comment: yw - I also learnt that quotes are optional in css, so we all gain something :)